# Excel - Count all non-blank cells, excluding empty string

Tags: excel

If I use `COUNTA(range)`, it counts cells with the empty string ("").  How do I avoid this?  `COUNTIFS(range,"<>"&"")` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ScottCraner: That doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For column **A**, cells **A1** through **A100** try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100<>""))
```

Comment: I don['t think that all visitors to this site would necessarily know to amend the range being specified here, and may go away with the idea that using entire column references within SUMPRODUCT Is ok, which of course it is not.